# Please help check the answer for finding the probability of people arriving

Tags: probability, statistics

People arrive at a variety store once every 10 minutes or so.

(a) What is the probability nobody arrives in the next 15 minutes?

**Ans: 0.223**

(b) What is the probability at least 3 people arrive in the next 20 minutes?

**Ans: 0.594**

(c) What is the expected number of arrivals in a 10 hour day?

**Ans: 60 people**

(d) Find the probability the first customer of the day arrives within the first half hour. 

**Ans: 0.865**

(e) Find the probability nobody arrives within the first 30 minutes.

**Ans: 0.05**

[image]

Updated Solution:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: a. looks good.  For b, though, if you model this on a Poisson process with mean $2$, the probability that you get $≤2$ people in $20$ minutes is $0.676676416$, so the answer would be $0.323323584$.  (didn't look at the others).

Comment: Well, your answers to d. and e. are contradictory (these two probabilities must add to $1$).

Comment: Your answers to (b) and (d) are wrong.

Comment: just post also some of your calculations...otherwise it's pretty hard to actually help you

Comment: @user190080 Hi, thank you for you answer. Could you please see the image above for my calculation? Thank you!

Comment: @almagest could you please help explain?

Comment: @lulu Could you please explain the correct way? Thank you

Comment: For b.  your calculation starts well, but it isn't complete.  You (correctly) subtract off the probabilities that nobody shows up and that exactly one person shows up.  To finish, all you have to do is subtract the probability that exactly $2$ people show up.

Comment: For $d$ you incorrectly use a mean of $2$.  In half an hour, the mean should be $3$ (which you correctly use in part e.).

Comment: (a) is fine. For (b) you forgot to subtract off the prob of 2 people arriving. (c) is fine. (d) if the first customer of the day does not arrive within 30 mins, then no one arrives in 30 mins and prob of that is same as (e), so you want $1-0.05=0.95$. (e) is fine.

Comment: @lulu Hi, thank you for that. Could you please confirm my updated solution? Thank you!

Comment: @almagest thank you  very much!

Comment: The updated solutions look good.

Comment: @lulu Hi, thank you for that. I just noticed something. On question A, can there by 1.5 people?

Comment: Of course.  That number is the mean...an average of possible value doesn't have to be a possible value.

Comment: @lulu Thank you, I was arguing with my friend about that :P

Comment: The mean value you get by rolling a fair die is $3.5$...which is not a possible value.  Just as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People arrive at a variety store once every 10 minutes or so. 

(a) What is the probability nobody arrives in the next 15 minutes? 

***Ans: 0.223*** 

(b) What is the probability at least 3 people arrive in the next 20 minutes? 

***Ans: 0.323***

(c) What is the expected number of arrivals in a 10 hour day? 

***Ans: 60 people*** 

(d) Find the probability the first customer of the day arrives within the first half hour. 

***Ans: 0.950***

(e) Find the probability nobody arrives within the first 30 minutes. 

***Ans: 0.05***

Thank you every who checked my work!

**Work:**
[image]